# Вывод blob-файла в браузер

Tags: php

Как вывести изображение blob из БД в браузер? Headers нельзя передать,поскольку до этого уже естественно была передана html-разметка. Додумался так :

```
<? // подключение к БД и т.д.
$data['image'] = $row['image'] // здесь блоб-файл
?>
<img src="/handler.php" />
```

handler.php отправит нужные  заголовки. **Но как** передать этому файлу саму картинку $data['image']. ??? Возможно эта реализация изначально неправильная. 
Кто-нибудь что-нибудь подскажет по этому поводу?
update, [[@klopp](/users/6550/klopp)](/users/6550/klopp), по-поводу если будет несколько картинок - в этой же таблице есть поле с html-кодом всей новости, там и img, и  все остальное, а вопрос был по поводу едпинственной картинки, которая должна быть превьюшкой в  каждой новости.

Comment: Передать в handler.php ID картинки в базе данных гет запросом?  
handler.php?getImage=1234

Comment: Ну да, получается, только сделал запрос в БД - и тут же 2й запрос касающийся тех же полей. Возможно есть вариант покрасивее?

Comment: Т.е. хотите достаточно тяжелое поле тащить с мускул-сервера дважды? Забавная логика. Я бы в такой ситуации вывел как-то так:

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,<?=base64_encode($data["image"]);?>" />`

Но это тот еще костыль. Лучше не хранить картинки в БД.

Comment: @Равнодушный, да, лучше не хранить. Не храню обычно, но в данном случае это лучший вариант - в таблице находятся поля : дата, краткое описание темы и мааааленькая png картинка. вот в чем проблемка.

Comment: Для маленьких пойдет мой пример по типу `data:URL`. Современные браузеры поддерживают.

Comment: @Равнодушный, действительно работает. Это вообще применяется? Или я буду первым? )))

Comment: @Равнодушный, уникальная конструкция, не подскажите где можно ознакомится с документацией таких хитростей?

Comment: Применяется. Правда, чаще в CSS вместо спрайтов для мелких часто встречающихся иконок. А так же иногда в html-письмах, чтобы картинки не вкладывать. Но base64 картинки весит процентов на 30 больше, чем картинка, так что увлекаться не стоит - заметно увеличит трафик.


З.Ы. ознакомиться - http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data:_URL

Comment: >в данном случае это лучший вариант - в таблице находятся поля : дата, краткое описание темы и мааааленькая png картинка

Это не лучший, а худший вариант :) В базе нужно хранить не картинку, а ссылку на неё. В каком виде - другой вопрос, часто достаточно просто INT, который будет служить именем картинки. Но лучше ID для другой таблицы с более полной информацией (линейные размеры, тип и т.д.). Переконвертировать существующую базу дело минутное.

Comment: @klopp с некоторых пор хранить blob/text в mysql можно и в той-же таблице, ключевое слово barracuda, для получения id не обязательно само поле с blob получать вообще-то.

Comment: Вопрос не "можно-нельзя", а насколько это эффективно. И оправдано с архитектурной точки зрения. Зачем " для получения id получать поле с blob" я вообще не понял.

Comment: ну вот в том и дело, что с barracuda неэффективно получается именно хранение блобов в отдельной таблице. 

про получение блобов это скорее в общую тему, просто возникал вопрос "Т.е. хотите достаточно тяжелое поле тащить с мускул-сервера дважды"

Comment: Тут ещё и вопрос архитектуры. Во-первых, к картинке надо и доп. данные хранить, как минимум размеры и тип. Но допустим, это всё задаётся жёстко, одинаковое для всех, и хранить не нужно. А если нужно, то ладно, мелочи. Но появляется во-вторых: а если со статьёй нужно будет связать не одну картинку?

Comment: не, ну я говорил конечно про таблицу для картинок, со всеми метаданными картинки, не таблица статьи конечно. Просто стандартная рекомендация с форматом antelope - хранить блобы в отдельной таблице, т.к. большие таблицы с блобами медленные и поэтому надо даже метаданные хранить отдельно. Дак вот судя по блогам mysqlperfomance  с barracuda это уже не нужно. вот про это и говорю, не более.

Comment: @Deus, для "картинки из заголовка" мне было бы влом вообще что-то отдельное заводить. ID статьи как имя + возможные правила поиска файла  на диске, если их очень много. Размеры и тип прошиваются. Всё, никаких данных отдельно для картинки в принципе не нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Заранее скажу, что не считаю хорошей идеей хранить данные в blob в mysql. Однако, отвечаю именно на Ваш вопрос. Можно сделать с помощью nginx так, чтобы можно было обращаться к файлу как /img/filename.ext.

Локейшн в nginx

```
#переадресует обращения, например, с  /img/land.png на handler.php?name=land.png
location ~* ^/img/(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri /handler.php?name=$1;
}
```

Допустим, есть таблица, где храниться имя файла, тип контента, и сам контент в blob_data

```
+----+--------------+----------+-----------+
| id | content_type | name     | blob_data |
+----+--------------+----------+-----------+
|  1 | image/png    | land.png | 21K       |
|  2 | image/png    | sky.png  | 21K       |
+----+--------------+----------+-----------+
```

файл handler.php

```
if (!isset($_GET['name']))
    notFound();

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=mysql;dbname=test;", 'admin', 'admin');
$q = $conn->prepare('SELECT content_type, blob_data FROM test WHERE name=? LIMIT 1');
$q->execute([$_GET['name']]);

$q->bindColumn(1, $content_type, PDO::PARAM_STR, 256);
$q->bindColumn(2, $blob_data, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOUND);

if (empty($content_type))
    notFound();

header("Content-Type: $content_type");
echo $blob_data;
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Прошло уже три два года с тех пор, как я задал вопрос))) Конечно, я отказался от идеи хранения файла в БД. ))) Но ответ ваш мне инересен!